# Xcode4, I use to be able to select some text and right click and search on that text in xcode3?

Tags: xcode, xcode4, xcode3to4

In Xcode 3 I use to be able to select some text, right click and search for that text.

However in Xcode 4 this seems to have disappeared ?

Is there a quick alternative instead ?

EDIT
I'd select some source code and it would find all occurences in the rest of the source code.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you mean by "search for that text"? For example, after selecting some text and right-clicking in Xcode 3, there's `Find in Project`, `Find Text in Documentation`, `Jump to Definition`, `Search in Spotlight`, and `Quick Help`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Select text; cmd-E

Then Shift-cmd-F; return

Boom.

Answer (score 1):

Select your text, hit command-E ("use selection for find") and command-G to iterate through results.

Comment: Hmmm, that only searches within the current file, not other source files / project :(

Comment: I thought you only wanted in a single file.   Shift-cmd-F is needed to do a multi file search, if you do the cmd-E first the S-C-F will be populated with the text you want so you can just hit return.

Answer (score 1):

Find in Workspace appears to be fundamentally broken in Xcode 4.

Someone else posted a workaround: toggle the Assistant Editor button to enable the menu item. However it still is not available for text in the debug output area.

Answer (score 0):

You can always try some keyboard shortcuts combination once your text is selected:

- <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>
- <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> (if you want to
  search in the current file, otherwise
  <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to look into the
  whole project)
- <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>

Then you can iterate through the results with <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> to go forward or <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> to go backward.

Hope this helps.

Comment: You can skip the copy-paste steps if you use ⌘E, ⇧⌘F

Answer (score 0):

Search in workspace (you can read the keyboard abbreviation in Edit -> Find -> find in workspace